# Why can't I access the keras.initializers class?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use the HeUniform() method from the keras.initializers class, bu when I go to run my code, I get the following output:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.initializers' has no attribute 'HeUniform'
```

The code that I ran is the following:

```
init = tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform()
```

My imports are:

```
import gym
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

from collections import deque
import time
import random
```

I'm using tensorflow version 2.0.0 installed from conda. I tried to upgrade the version, but I was getting further errors saying that version 2.2.0 and 2.4.1 does not exist for conda. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [tensorflow api documentation for version 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/all_symbols). There is no class `tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform`. Instead, there is a function [`tf.keras.initializers.he_uniform`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers.). You can find the source code for the function [on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py#L702-L720).

TensorFlow recommends installing with `pip`. In the past, I have created a new conda environment specifically for tensorflow. It is bad practice to mix conda and pip packages, so that's why I create a new environment just for the specific version of tensorflow.

```
conda create -n tf2 python=3.8
conda activate tf2
python -m pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow==2.4.1
```

Just keep in mind that the GPU versions depend on specific versions of CUDA and cuDNN. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu for more information about the requirements.

Comment: Great! If this solved your problem, please click the green check mark to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar problem, but this solution isn't working. Could you help me with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927838/specifying-a-weight-initialiser-returns-an-error-could-not-interpret-initialize